# I'm confused with the role of method called .next() in java and jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I use .next() in java string to return the value what comes before white_space

e.g. `"hello world"=> returns "hello"`

But in jdbc:

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){ 
     //do something
}
```

I use it with the moto

> "If the result set still has results, move to the next result and do
>   something"

So I'm confused with the role. Please someone clarify it.

Comment: It isn't the same `next`. They do (and are meant to do) different things.

Comment: You're conflating `Scanner.next` with `ResultSet.next`.

Comment: Both functions are not related in any way but the name.

Comment: And, this should be obvious, but when wondering what a method does and what its role is, what you should do is read its documentation. Scanner.next(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--; ResultSet.next(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All standard Java classes are documented: [Java API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Example:

1. [ResuttSet.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--)

   > Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
   >
   > ...
2. [Scanner.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--)

   > Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.
   >
   > ...